# Image animation effects using masking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating an small animation for images using CSS and jQuery. In the following code I have used the `scroll` function to make the animation working on scrolling.

[JS-Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x2xjhmc4/)

Here is the code:

```
<section class="section1" id="ideal" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="1s">
   <h3>The Thought</h3>
      <div class="animate">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="img/pic1.jpg"/>
          <div class="mask">
          </div>
      </div>
   <p class="" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="1s">Lorem Ipsum</p>
</section>
```

And my jQuery is:

```
$(window).one('scroll',function(){
   $('.animate>.mask').animate({
     'opacity': '50'
   }, {
      step: function (now, fx) {
        $(this).css({"transform": "translate3d("+ now +"px, 0px, 0px)"});
    },
    duration: 3000,
    easing: 'linear',
    queue: false,

}, 'linear');
$(".animate>.mask").animate({ textIndent: 30 }, {
    duration : 3000,
    easing: 'linear',
    queue: false
});
})
```

And CSS:

```
.mask{
background: #fff;
bottom: 0;
height: 82%;
right:0;
position: absolute; 
width: 15%;
margin:7.5% 0;
z-index: 100;
top:100%;
}
```

In this I am trying to use for `five` section. Here the problem is it working only one time and the `mask` CSS which I have used is also working for one section, the remaining section are all not working.

Comment: typo in `$(window).one('scroll',function(){`

Comment: please check this [JS-Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x2xjhmc4/). The animation is working when scrolling happens

Comment: @kukkuz Maybe he really wants to fire the scroll callback once...?

Comment: There's no animation for me when I run the fiddle (Chrome 60 on macOS)